# What CPU instruction sets extensions are needed to support the target 'riscv32' for Linux/GCC?

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, compilation, cpu-architecture, riscv

I was looking into Linux [support](https://risc-v-getting-started-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/linux-qemu.html#:%7E:text=Then%20compile%20the%20kernel) for the RISC-V 32 Bit and came across the following compile instructions:

```
make ARCH=riscv CROSS_COMPILE=riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu- -j $(nproc)
```

The issue is that `riscv32` does not make it clear if just the base CPU instruction set is needed (RV32I) or if additional extensions are needed/toggleable (`RV32IMAC` seems to be a common target).

This leaves me with the following questions:

- What CPU instruction set or sets is implied in above command?
- If not RV32I, can optional arguments be added to support RV32I?

Comment: Why worry about it? The Makefile of the kernel should have the job to supply the correct compiler flags to enable specific extensions if needed.

Comment: *"What CPU instruction set or sets is implied in above command?"* - none specifically, it depends on how the compiler you are using was configured and what options are being passed by the Makefile. In your case the compiler is going to be `riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-cc` (or `-gcc`).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli `Why worry about it?` It determines what type of RIS-V emulator I need on the microcontroller/FPGA. The simpler, the easier. There are open source RV32I emulations for microcontrollers.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli to elaborate, if i put the effort into getting a RV32I working for a target and the compiler uses  RV32IMAC instructions then it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see in the Linux kernel v5.19 the `Makefile` for RISC-V ([`arch/riscv/Makefile`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19/source/arch/riscv/Makefile)) looks like this:

```
# ISA string setting
riscv-march-$(CONFIG_ARCH_RV32I)    := rv32ima
riscv-march-$(CONFIG_ARCH_RV64I)    := rv64ima
riscv-march-$(CONFIG_FPU)           := $(riscv-march-y)fd
riscv-march-$(CONFIG_RISCV_ISA_C)   := $(riscv-march-y)c
```

The ISA used is `rv32ima` for 32-bit RISC-V kernels. Additionally, the `f`, `d` and `c` extensions can also be enabled by configuring `CONFIG_FPU` (for `fd`) and `CONFIG_RISCV_ISA_C` (for `c`). By default these two are both set to `y` so you have `rv32imafdc`, however you can disable `fdc` if you run `menuconfig` (or similar) and set `CONFIG_FPU=n` and `CONFIG_RISCV_ISA_C=n`.

Note: this is for Linux v5.19. You will have to make sure yourself by inspecting the `Makefile` of your kernel if you have a different version.

> can optional arguments be added to support RV32I?

No, it does not look like so, `rv32ima` is the minimum set of extensions selected when tarteging RISC-V 32bit. But again, if you have a different kernel version lower than v5.19 you'd have to check your `Makefile` to make sure (maybe some older kernels are fine with just `rv32i`).